# Strange bulge on wall

Tags: walls

I’m looking for some advice please. I noticed this when I moved into the property several years ago, but I was just curious as to what may have caused it. The “bulge” is actually in line with the wall on the right side, but it feels like the area between the window and the bulge is further in than the rest of the wall. The whole area feels stable when I push against it, with no movement, and no evidence of water leakage. Am I right in thinking it’s just the way the wall settled? The property was built in 1888 so pretty old! Sorry for the poor picture, but it’s only really noticeable when I have a light on. Thank you for any insight! [image]

Comment: Do not exactly the cause, but the age might suggest a stud is not in perfect alignment with the rest of the studs and when the drywall mud was applied they did not feather it out enough to hide it better.  Enjoy the bulge and think of it adding character to the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Just poor plaster/drywall finishing, evidently. Not settling (no cracks evident.) Could be "fixed" if you find it an issue by redoing the wall finish there, or you could "fix" it by not worrying about a minor lump in a 135 year old building.

Comment: +1  for fix it by not worrying about it